# Redshift query a daily-generated table

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am looking for a way to create a Redshift query that will retrieve data from a table that is generated daily. Tables in our cluster are of the form:

```
event_table_2016_06_14
event_table_2016_06_13
```

.. and so on.

I have tried writing a query that appends the current date to the table name, but this does not seem to work correctly (invalid operation):

```
SELECT * FROM concat('event_table_', to_char(getdate(),'YYYY_MM_DD'))
```

Any suggestions on how this can be performed are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm facing the same problem and trying to figure out the best possible approach. It would be nice if you could share your experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried writing a query that appends the current date to the
>   table name, but this does not seem to work correctly (invalid
>   operation):

Redshift does not support that. But you most likely won't need it.

Try the following (expanding on the answer from @ketan):

1. Create your main table with appropriate (for joins) DIST key, and COMPOUND or simple SORT KEY on timestamp column, and proper compression on columns.
2. Daily, create a temp table (use `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE` - this will preserve DIST/SORT keys), load it with daily data, `VACUUM SORT`.
3. Copy *sorted* temp table into main table using `ALTER TABLE APPEND` - this will copy the data sorted, and will reduce VACUUM on the main table. You may still need `VACUUM SORT` after that.

After that query your main table normally, probably giving it a range on timestamp. Redshift is optimised for these scenarios, and 99% of times you don't need to optimise table scans yourself - even on tables with billion of rows scans take milliseconds to few seconds. You may need to optimise elsewhere, but that's the second step.

To get insight in the performance of scans, use STL_QUERY system table to find your query ID, and then use STL_SCAN (or SVL_QUERY_SUMMARY) table to see how fast the scan was.

Your example is actually the main use case for [ALTER TABLE APPEND](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE_APPEND.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are creating a new table everyday.

What you can do is:

1. [Create a view](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_VIEW.html) on top of `event_table_*` tables. Query your data using this view.
2. Whenever you create or drop a table, update the view.

If you want, you can avoid #2: Instead of creating a new table everyday, create empty tables for next 1-2 years. So, no need to update the view every day. However, do remember that there is an upper [limit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/amazon-redshift-limits.html#amazon-redshift-limits-quota) of 9,900 tables in Redshift.

**Edit**: If you always need to query today's table (instead of all tables, as I assumed originally), I don't think you can do that without updating your view.

However, you can modify your design to have just one table, with `date` as sort-key. So, whenever your table is queried with some `date`, all disk blocks that don't have that `date` will be skipped. That'll be as efficient as having time-series tables.

Comment: Right, but ultimately I don't want to have to update the view on a daily basis. I'm trying to find a way to have the SQL automatically use today's date in the table name.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do that

Comment: and your question wasn't very clear on that.. if you just need to look at today's data, why create time-series tables. just create one table, with date as sort-key. that'll be efficient enough